# C# - Set up the default user directory with Desktop, AppData etc. for a new user who has never logged in before

Tags: c#, windows-7, .net-3.5

I've been tasked with developing an installer that creates and sets up a new local user account with predefined accessibility to our windows application before first login. As we know, the user's directory in C:\Users is only created when the user logs in for the first time. This means that I have to also create the user's directory in C:\Users and the Desktop and AppData directories within.

I have already created the User and the directories programmatically. However, while manually logging into the user account for the first time, Windows goes through the pains of creating and assigning a different user directory, completely ignoring the directory that I would have wanted the user to be able use.

I have thought of some possible workarounds, but they all require the user to login manually. Is there a way of approaching this problem without the user account having been logged into before?

Comment: If you only need your app to be available, why don't you install it for "Everyone" instead of "Just me"? In this way the app will be available for all users no matter when it's created...

Comment: @Gusman  The app is to be accessible only from the Administrator and the new user. Unfortunately, access to "Everyone" is not an option.

Comment: Which OS is? If it's a new one then you may use a Group Policy to automatically install the software when the user logs on for the first time: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816102/how-to-use-group-policy-to-remotely-install-software-in-windows-server

Comment: You need to have let windows do its thing before you do yours.

Comment: @Gusman The installer is supposed to create the user - the user does not typically exist before installation. The aim is to run the installer from an administrator account, with the app ready to be used from the new user. I have some ideas where pending setup tasks are automatically completed once the user logs in, but I would like to know if I can avoid that.

Comment: That's what the group policy achieves, you create a group policy for an user group, then when you create the user only wih adding it to the group it will install the software when the user logs on.